# PHP conditional session_destroy not working as expected

Tags: php

I am writing code for math problems -- they follow a format, with randomly generated variables, and then I lock in the variables per the code below.  What isn't working -- form03 allows the user to finish the page of math problems and to reset for another.  I need to destroy the session on that condition.  But even when I enter data in form03, so that it isset, the old session values remain.
???

```
require_once 'random.php';
require_once 'forms-functions.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['z'])) {
   $_SESSION['y'] = "";
   session_start();
   session_destroy();
}

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['y'])) {
   echo "hello isset<br>";
   $x01 = $_SESSION['x01'];
   $x02 = $_SESSION['x02'];
   $output01b = $_SESSION['output01b'];
   $output02b = $_SESSION['output02b'];

} else {
   echo "hello else<br>";

   ob_start();
   random1();
   $output01 = ob_get_clean();
   $output01b = "single string: ".$output01."";
   $x01 = $x;

   ob_start();
   random1();
   $output02 = ob_get_clean();
   $output02b = "single string: ".$output02."";
   $x02 = $x;

   $_SESSION['x01'] = $x01;
   $_SESSION['x02'] = $x02;
   $_SESSION['output01b'] = $output01b;
   $_SESSION['output02b'] = $output02b;

   $y = "1";
   $_SESSION['y'] = $y;     
}

echo $output01b;
$user_input01 = form01('user_input01');

echo $output02b;
$user_input02 = form02('user_input02');

$user_input03 = form03('user_input03');

if(isset($user_input03)) {
   $z = 1;
   $_SESSION['z'] = $z;
   echo "hello \$z";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `session_start()` before you try to access the session variable `z`. And you need to set the new session variable `y` after you destroy the old session and start a new one.

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['z'])) {
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['y'] = "";
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  That didn't work.  After a few inputs, I ended up with a strange scenario of seeing the "hello isset" echo, yet getting Undefined Index Notices for all four terms in the if-comparison isset($_SESSION['y']).

Comment: Your code assumes that when `y` is set, so is `x01` and `x02`. But `y` is set when destroying the session, so none of the other session variables will be set. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `y` when you set it before destroying the session.

Comment: Thanks -- I think I needed not only to move that reset of SESSION['y'] after the destroy, but also just to get rid of that reset of SESSION['y'] altogether (and the rest of that first IF comparison now stands in the order you suggested)....  However, I still cannot get my session to restart when I enter a value for $user_input03.  I *do* get the echo "hello \$z," but the session values are still set (unless I manually destroy the session unconditionally).

Comment: Since you're checking for `z` at the beginning of the script, the session won't be destroyed until you go to the next page after `$user_input03` is entered. Maybe you really want to destroy the session in the `if(isset($user_input03))` block

Comment: Oh, this gets me mostly there -- put the destroy command inside if comparison if(isset($user_input03)) -- however, I have to submit value in that form twice before the session is destroyed -- the first time, I do get my echo confirmation, but the $output01b & 02b do not change until I that second time I hit enter for a value in user_input03.

Comment: It's really hard for me to help with this, because I have no idea what the functions `form01()`, `form02()`, etc. do. You haven't posted enough for me to understand all the flow between the different forms.